# Limit a dataset by the max of a groupby

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgres sql how would you conduct an analysis which involves a count over a groupby (2 columns) but limit the output of the dataset to the max x rows of a groupby over just 1 of the columns?

```
| Groupby_1 | Groupby_2 |
|-----------|-----------|
| a         | x         |
| a         | y         |
| b         | x         |
| b         | x         |
| b         | z         |
```

Expected Output Before Limiting

```
| Groupby_1 | Groupby_2 | Count |
|-----------|-----------|-------|
| a         | x         | 1     |
| a         | y         | 1     |
| b         | x         | 2     |
| b         | z         | 1     |
```

Post Limiting by a sum(count) over groupby_1 Limit 1

```
| Groupby_1 | Groupby_2 | Count |
|-----------|-----------|-------|
| b         | x         | 2     |
| b         | z         | 1     |
```

The output is limited to the data from the second table where the group_by over groupby_1 is the largest but it still displays all the associated rows to b from the second table

I thought the below would get me close but it doesn't give me the equivalent table from 2 i just end up with a sum of count over groupby_1.

```
SELCT SUM(count) AS sum_count, groupby_1
FROM (
   SELECT
   COUNT(*) as count, groupby_1, groupby_2
   FROM table
   GROUP BY groupby_1, groupby_2
) ab
GROUP BY groupby_1
```

Any help would be appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions with aggregation:

```
SELECT ab.*  -- or whatever columns you want
FROM (SELECT ab.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY groupby_1_cnt DESC, groupby_1) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT groupby_1, groupby_2, COUNT(*) as cnt,
                 SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (groupby_1) as groupby_1_cnt
            FROM table
            GROUP BY groupby_1, groupby_2
           ) ab
    ) ab
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Alternatively, you could use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT groupby_1, groupby_2, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY groupby_1, groupby_2
HAVING groupby_1 = (SELECT groupby_1
                    FROM table
                    GROUP BY groupby_1
                    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                   );
```